# If data in a recycler view item is null don't display the view holder

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to check if data that comes from the server is null or not. If is not null then populate the recycler view item in my case being a CardView and if it is null don't display the CardView at all.

In my recycler view adapter i have this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    var firstName = itemsList[position].firstName
    var lastName = itemsList[position].lastName

    if (firstName.isNullOrEmpty() && lastName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        //...what shoud i write here ?
    } else {
        holder.name?.text = firstName + " " + lastName
     }
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val name = itemView.name
}
```

Comment: I think this should be handled from `getItemViewType` method of `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly can I do that? I am relatively new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do something like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    var firstName = itemsList[position].firstName
    var lastName = itemsList[position].lastName

    if (firstName.isNullOrEmpty() && lastName.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        yourCardView.visibility = View.INVISIBLE //or GONE if you do not want to keep its space
        holder.name?.text = ""
    } else {
        yourCardView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.name?.text = firstName + " " + lastName
     }
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val name = itemView.name
}
```

but if cardview is your root item and you do not want to show the list item at all,you should change your main list with a code like this in your adapter constructor:

```
        filteredList = itemsList?.filter {
            (it.firstname.isNullOrEmpty() || it.lastName.isNullOrEmpty()).not()
        }
```

Comment: Can I set my cardView visibility in another way? I can't access it in adapter.

Comment: if cardview is in your list-item you should findViewById it in ViewHolder and access it same as holder.name (for example holder.cardView.visibility) but if cardview is in your activity you should hide it by passing an interface that implemented in your activity or pass it in adapter constructor

Comment: Thank you so much it works now. One more thing though...even if I set the visibility to View.GONE the space of the cardView is still showing in the list.

Comment: set your item's height wrap_content and add this code in your activity : recyclerView.hasFixedSize = false it should works

Answer (score 0):

Even if you change the visibility of the `CardView` the gap in the `RecyclerView` will be there.  
It's better to remove the empty items from the list, prior to setting the adapter:

```
list.removeIf { it.firstName.isNullOrEmpty() && it.lastName.isNullOrEmpty() }
```